# How do i make form variable to display on all my site pages?

Tags: php, html, forms

This is my form:

```
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="tracking.php">
  <label>
    <input type="text" name="trckno_trk" id="trckno_trk" />
  </label>
  <label>
    <input type="submit" name="button" id="button" value="Submit" />
  </label>
</form>
```

When i submit my form, the submitted form variable displays well on the "tracking.php" page using `<?php echo $_POST['trckno_trk']; ?>`.

But when i click on other pages in the site, it doesn't seem to display. That mean that the form variable `echo $_POST['trckno_trk']` displays only on one page but does not display on any other page.

Please, how can i get it to display on every other page on my site.

Comment: save it in `Session` and then use it on other pages

Comment: Please consider using the `htmlspecialchars` function in your form's `action` to convert special characters to html entities. Your form is vulnerable to XSS.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
   <?php
// Start the session
session_start();
?>
```

Then you html

```
    <form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="tracking.php">
  <label>
    <input type="text" name="trckno_trk" id="trckno_trk" />
  </label>
  <label>
    <input type="submit" name="button" id="button" value="Submit" />
  </label>
</form>
```

Then you should save the variable in your `Session`

```
 <?php echo $_POST['trckno_trk'];
     $_SESSION["trckno_trk"] = $_POST['trckno_trk'];
 ?>
```

Now you can use this `Session` to display on other pages.

Answer (score 0):

Form submited data are available only for page you specified in action parameter. They are not stored in any way. You need to save them for example in database or SESSION variables and retrive them again when accessing other pages.

Answer (score 0):

Form parameters are accesible only when you post them, to use them later you will need to save them somewhere.

If you'd like to save the value & display it everywhere for all clients, you will need to store it in a database (e.g. [MySQL](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php)), fetch the value and print it

If you'd like it to be unique for each client, you could use cookies, for example:

```
setcookie('cookiename',
'the value', 
time()+86400 /* seconds until it expires */, 
'/' /* On what pages do you want to use it, '/' means all pages*/, 
);
```

The code above saves the cookie, to print its value:

```
echo $_COOKIE['cookiename'];
```

Another option is to save it in the session, but it will expire after a short time

```
session_start(); // put this on the start of every page to start the session
$_SESSION['name'] = 'value'; // save a value in the session
echo $_SESSION['name']; // print it
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use $_SESSION[] to store your POSTED value, this way you will be able to access it on any other page.
So on your tracking.php you can have code like this

```
 session_start();
 $_SESSION['trckno_trk']=$_POST['trckno_trk'];
```

then on other pages you can access the variable using

```
session_start();
echo $_SESSION['trckno_trk'];
```